# How can I derive the following dual problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Standard form of the linear program is
$$\text{Min} \,  C^{T} x$$
$$ s.t.    Ax=b $$
$$x\ge 0$$

Dual is
$$\text{Max}\, b^Ty$$
$$s.t.   C-A^{T}y \ge 0$$

By using the above definition, I want to find the dual of the following linear problem and convert it into the standard form.

$$\text{Min} \, -
  {\left[\begin{array}{r}
   b \\
    -b   \\
    0
  \end{array}\right]}^{T}  {\left[\begin{array}{r}
   y_1 \\
    y_2   \\
    S
  \end{array}\right]}
$$
$$ s.t.  (A^T, -A^T , I) {\left[\begin{array}{r}
   y_1 \\
    y_2   \\
    S
  \end{array}\right]}=C
$$
$$y_1, y_2,S \ge 0$$

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *your* definition of the dual, the primal problem can be transformed to

\begin{align}
& \max Z = C^T u \\
& \text{s.t. } -{\left[\begin{array}{r} b \\ -b \\ 0\end{array}\right]} - {\left[\begin{array}{r} A \\ -A \\ I \end{array}\right]} u \ge 0.
\end{align}

Simplify this to

\begin{align}
\max Z = C^T u & \\
\text{s.t. } Au &\le -b \\
Au &\ge -b \\
u &\le 0.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\max Z = C^T u & \\
\text{s.t. } Au &= -b \\
u &\le 0.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\max Z = C^T (-u) & \\
\text{s.t. } A(-u) &= -b \\
u &\ge 0.
\end{align}

Finally, we get

\begin{align}
\min Z = C^T u & \\
\text{s.t. } Au &= b \\
u &\ge 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! I hope this is correct!!!!